# Cakephp 3.x: accessing variable through associated table

Tags: cakephp, associations

I have an expense table that has an associated Annual Operating Budget table.

```
$this->belongsTo('AnnualOperatingBudgets', [
            'foreignKey' => 'annual_operating_budgets_id'
        ]);
```

That Annual Operating Budget Table is associated with an AZinstitution table.

```
$this->belongsTo('Azinstitutions', [
            'foreignKey' => 'azinstitutions_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
```

When I view an Expense I can display the foreignKey to the Institution Table that is in the Annual Operating Budget table but what I want to display the Institution name associated with the Institution table. Is that possible? Or do i also need to add the 'azinstitutions_id' as a foreign Key to my Expense Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrive Azinstitutions details along with AnnualOperatingBudgets using containable

From ExpensesController.php

```
public function view($id)
{
     $expense = $this->Expenses->findById($id)
        ->contain('AnnualOperatingBudgets.Azinstitutions')
        ->first();
     //get institution name from $expense->annual_operating_budget->azinstitution->name
      ... }
```

Comment: That worked perfect RogerSSD. In the expence controller I added. the above and then in the view I was able to see the items in the variables and call it. Solved. :-)